# OpsHub VSO migration - DataValidationException - Test Suite already exists

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

During an OpsHub migration from local TFS 2013.3 server to VSO, I receive an error message from OpsHub:

com.opshub.exceptions.DataValidationException: OpbsHug-012017: Field mapping with name: Migrate Work Items and Version Control Data Migrate Work Items and Version Control Data | TFS Source 1211589216815 ALM TFS 1211589216816 'All' Test Suite already exists

This only occurs when trying to migrate work items.  Code migration works fine on its own.  Stack trace from log file shown below:

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at TFSMigrationUI.ViewModel.MigrationSummeryViewModel.createConfigWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(Object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) in e:\5.7Checkout\VSMUTFSMigration\TFSMigrationUI\ViewModel\MigrationSummeryViewModel.cs:line 635
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
2014-09-24 16:07:30,517 [1] ERROR com.opshub.exceptions.DataValidationException: OpsHub-012017: Field mapping with name : Migrate Work Items and Version Control Data Migrate Work Items and Version Control Data| TFS Source 1411589216815 ALM TFS 1411589216816 'All' Test Suite  already exists
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: com.opshub.exceptions.DataValidationException: OpsHub-012017: Field mapping with name : Migrate Work Items and Version Control Data Migrate Work Items and Version Control Data| TFS Source 1411589216815 ALM TFS 1411589216816 'All' Test Suite  already exists

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the error message and information provided it looks like you are using TFS 2013 update 3 which is currently not supported by free migration utility. We will update you on same thread once we have support for this tfs version.

Thanks,

OpsHub

Comment: does the paid version support it?  If so, where can I buy the full version of OpsHub?

Comment: There are some structural changes in TFS 2013 Update 3 which need to be supported. The support for it is coming soon.